# Wireless Debugging not working in Android Studio on MAC

Tags: android-studio, avd-manager, android-wireless

I am trying to connect my Realme Mobile ,(Working on Android 13, Updated to latest version) and facing difficult to connect my phone to Android Studio on MAC for wireless debugging.

I tried to connect through QR scanner method but as soon as I scan the code, I get no response and even after scanning for > 2 minutes, nothing is happening.

Also the pairing code method is not working. Most of the times my device is never showed up in list. And If it is then the TCP port is outdated and after entering the pairing code, it displays that it is failed to connect.

Even if the TCP port is correct then many times it shows that it will take 2 minutes to connect but it never connects.

The success ratio to connect is 1/100.

Please suggest the best possible setting for android phone and MAC laptop for wireless debugging.

Comment: Have you found the answer? I'm running into the same issue at the moment

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have same issue. You can try manual pair with ADB command. After pairing sometimes Android Studio auto connects to paired device otherwise you can manually connect to device.

In your phone open Wireless debugging -> Pair device with pairing code

In terminal (Inside android studio)

```
adb pair 192.168.0.***:#####
*** your IP
##### your port
```

It will require pairing code, after entering code it must auto connect to device, if not, you should connect manually.

```
adb connect 192.168.0.***:#####
*** your IP
##### your port
```

NOTE: Pairing port and connecting ports are different

Comment: I'm getting this:
`error: protocol fault (couldn't read status message): Undefined error: 0`

Comment: I had same issue try to reboot your phone. After reboot try to type command
"adb mdns services" to see visible devices
NOTE: each device must have one connection port otherwise reboot is required

Comment: @keaukraine i resolved it on android by clicking on pair device with pairing code and then use the latest ip & port provide and then enter the pairing code